# How do I split an array into two different arrays and also, how do i allow the user to only enter in part of the array and not the maximum amount?

Tags: c#, arrays

I can't figure out how to split my array correctly so that I can pass those two separate arrays to multiple different methods. I also would like to end the array at any point without the program giving the user an error. Can anyone give me some direction on what to do and help me fix my program?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace proj09LEA
{
    class Program
    {
        // declare a constant integer
        const int MAX = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare and array of integers
            int[] array = new int[MAX];

            Console.WriteLine("\nSaturday Coder's Bowling Team");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score for each person on the team.");
            Console.WriteLine("For example, Mary 143. Just hit Enter when you are done.\n");

            // fill an array with user input
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                // ask the user to enter some data
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score: ");
                // the line of data input by the user is stored here
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                // userInput is split into two pieces, which are stored in this array
                string[] parsedInput;
                // this line splits the string userInput into two pieces
                parsedInput = userInput.Split();
                // store the first piece, the name, in a string array
                string names = parsedInput[0];
                // store the second piece, a score, in an integer variable
                int scores = int.Parse(parsedInput[1]);
                array[i] = scores;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("------------ Input Complete ------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the scores for this game:");

            // display the scores for each person from method DisplayScores
            DisplayScore(array);
            // display the highest score and name of player from method HighScore
            HighScore(array);
            // display the lowest score and name of player from method LowScore
            LowScore(array);
            // display the average score from method AverageScore
            AverageScore(array);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue. . .");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DisplayScore(int[] array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}'s score was {0}.\n", array[i]);
            }
        }

        static void HighScore(int[] array)
        {
            int max = array.Max();
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations {0}, your score of {0} was the highest.", max);
        }

        static void LowScore(int[] array)
        {
            int min = array.Min();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, your score of {0} was the lowest. Better get some practice.", min);
        }

        static void AverageScore(int[] array)
        {
            int sum = array.Sum();
            int average = sum / array.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("The average score for this game was {0:d}.", average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't have string array???? and what is your input format

Comment: when you need such functionality, consider using List<int>. array is fixed in size.

Answer (score 0):

If you willing to input inputs one by one first name then after scores one by one

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name: ");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a score "+i+": ");
                string score = Console.ReadLine();
                // store the second piece, a score, in an integer variable
                int scores = int.Parse(score);
                array[i] = scores;
            }
```